# JDO Exception when using Query::executeWithMap(Map parameters) method

Tags: sql, exception, jdo

I'm composing a dynamic SQL query that contains named parameters, one of the them is `signerName`. It's used in the query as the following:

```
"LOWER(`CG_TRANSACTIONSIGNER`.`FIRSTNAME`) LIKE :signerName"
```

When setting the parameter as `params.put("signerName", signerName);`, the `Query::executeWithMap(Map parameters)` method will return a collection of `[Ljava.lang.Object;` which is wrong. It's supposed to return a collection of `Transaction`. This is the complete stack trace:

```
org.datanucleus.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "The class "[Ljava.lang.Object;" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found." is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data for the class is not found.
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:241)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoDetachCopy(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1110)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1183)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.java:166)
    at com.cryptolog.universign.sign.impl.ContractSignStore.getTransactionsBySQL(ContractSignStore.java:274)
    at com.cryptolog.universign.sign.impl.ContractSignStoreTest.testSqlFilterEquivalentToJdqlFilter(ContractSignStoreTest.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
The class "[Ljava.lang.Object;" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "[Ljava.lang.Object;" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.assertClassPersistable(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3890)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.detachObjectCopy(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1840)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoDetachCopy(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1105)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1183)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManagerProxy.java:166)
    at com.cryptolog.universign.sign.impl.ContractSignStore.getTransactionsBySQL(ContractSignStore.java:274)
    at com.cryptolog.universign.sign.impl.ContractSignStoreTest.testSqlFilterEquivalentToJdqlFilter(ContractSignStoreTest.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: You post a question allegedly about some query (incomplete query provided so nothing to comment on), yet provide some stack trace about "detach" (using some _ancient_ version of DataNucleus). Suggest you focus on what it is you're doing. What comes back from a JDOQL query using DataNucleus follows the JDO spec exactly (as per the JDO TCK), so please provide the complete definition of that query then people can comment on facts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong. Actually the result returned by the `Query::executeWithMap(Map parameters)`, the collection of `[Ljava.lang.Object;`, is a normal result. the `[Ljava.lang.Object;` type is an array of java.lang.Object which was the result of executing the SQL query. This type is not persistable and that's why the `ClassNotPersistenceCapableException` exception will be thrown when calling the  `PersistenceManager::detachCopy(Transaction pc)` method.